# Linux debian 8, xfce, проблема с переключением раскладки

Tags: linux, debian, qt4, xfce

Работаю в IDE Qt4, система Linux debian 8, графическая оболочка xfce. Когда переключаю раскладку, первая введённая буква игнорируется (вообще не вводится), а дальше начинает вводиться всё нормально.

Причём это происходит именно при вводе в редакторе Qt, при вводе, например, в браузере, всё нормально.

Никто с таким не встречался? Как это можно побороть?

Comment: Где-то ошибка, первое событие от устройства ввода «проглатывается» приложением.

Comment: То есть это баг среды, а не я что-то в настройках напуршил?

Comment: Из текущего описания неочевидно. Создайте нового пользователя, и запустите с настройками по умолчанию. Это отсечёт круг поиска.